# Convert NSDictionary in two NSArrays for objects and keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` that contains multiple objects and keys. How do I convert this dictionary in two `NSArrays`, one that contains the keys and one that contains the objects?

Comment: Please read the docs for `NSDictionary`. It has two methods that do this already.

Comment: @Lukas You are getting down voted because you did not take the effort to look at the documentation, actually finding out what methods are available in the `NSDictionary` class. (Did not down vote.)

Comment: @Zaph Thanks! I'll search more in the class documentation next time.

Comment: You might check into a 3rd party documentation viewer such as [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash), many people find it quite useful.

Comment: @Zaph I'm already using Dash, but thank you. Ill search more properly next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];
NSArray *objects = [dictionary allValues];
```